# skype icon turns to an invalid icon in ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, skype

The skype icon turns to an invalid image few minutes after starting it. I started facing the problem after upgrading to ubuntu 16.10. Hence, it's difficult identify whether any notifications are pending to read or not. 
I think the problem occurs while returning back from lock screen but not sure. It's just an observation.

```
Skype version: 4.3.0.37
Ubuntu version: 16.10
```

Attaching the screenshot for the reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found this thread: [Icons missing in systray (skype and others) / Desktop / Xfce Forums](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8799)

If I kill indicator-application-service

```
 kill -HUP $(pidof indicator-application-service)
```

and restart it

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service &
```

The icons are ok.

Comment: I have tried to kill & restart the "indicator-application-service" as suggested in the same thread earlier but it was of No Luck.
That's why I was forced to go with StackOverFlow :-)

Comment: I suspect that the problem is generated by Skype itself: if I close skype, all icons in tray are ok.

Answer (score 0):

In my case skype icon becomes invalid after I lock my notebook.

If I Quit and relaunch skype, the icon is fine till the next lock.

Comment: Just run software updater, choose settings..., select developer options tab and check pre-released updates (yakkety proposed). After reloading and downloading all updates the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and found that it's a bug of unity which already fixed but will be released with ubuntu 17.04. But you can install fixed version from ppa. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1635625